# Inverting amplifier saturation with capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier

R1 represents a resistive sensor in the figure below. In reality, it has also a capacitor in parallel. I'm trying to understand the effect of this capacitor. When a parallel C(is labelled as C2) is added, the output is saturated. What is the explanation of this? How can i tackle this C which negatively affect the output? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a parallel C(is labelled as C2) is added, the output is
>   saturated. What is the explanation of this?

At 2 kHz, the 5 nF cap has an impedance of  about 16 kohm. Because it is in parallel with a resistor of value 300 kohm, the op-amp gain is increased about twenty times and it is much more likely that the op-amp output will saturate.

> How can i tackle this C which negatively affect the output?

Put a 15 nF capacitor across R5 to "balance" the effect of the 5 nF across R1. However, the op-amp output may show signs of instability so, also try a 100 ohm resistor in series with V1.

Comment: Thanks, acc. to  my calculation the impedance of 5nF at 2kHz is about 16kohm. Nop. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: C2 is also variable with R1, so it's dependent to R1. It is not easy to adjust also C1 capacitor on the fly.

Comment: Oops yes. I calculated for 1 kHz. Fixed now.

Comment: @BerkerIşık did you try adding a capacitor across R5 to counter the effect of the 5 nF?

Comment: Yes, I've added 15nF in simulation. Beacuse of C , gain is 1/3 as expected. Thanks for this. But the problem was dynamically changing value of R1. In this time the question is, how to set C every time according to the R1 to maintain the ratio R5/R1.

Comment: So your question isn’t actually answered then?

Comment: Actually it was answered. Adding C across R5 was your advice. But this was a solution of the problem. My question was like this what is the reason of the problem? Thanks

Comment: So why was the other answer accepted?

Comment: In fact, both answers says the reason the problem. But in yours there is an extra explanation. You're right. Yours deserve the accepted.

Comment: I think you have some words to say for my unanswered question here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461655/opamp-input-offset-voltage-when-saturation

Comment: @BerkerIşık I cannot add anything to that answer and comments. You are getting a non-virtual earth because the opamp is unable to drive its output above 5 volts in order to balance the negative input voltage at the gain used. This happens when the output reaches saturation; it can no longer sustain a virtual earth.

Answer (score 1):

At 2kHz the impedance of C2 is 16kOhm, hence your amplifier acts like if R1 was equal to 300kOhm || 16kOhm = 15kOhm

Without the capacitor, your gain is -1/3 but with the capacitor the gain becomes -6.7 and hence you saturate the op amp (1V * 6.7 = 6.7 V pick > 5V pick)